# Whats the relation between a module and a process in Erlang

Tags: module, process, erlang

I am new to Erlang trying to understand what's the relation of a module and a process in Erlang.
Dose each module spun up a new process in BEAM ?
When we call a function from another module is there message passing been done between two process ?

I tried to search go through Erlang docs, while working on a existing Erlang code

Comment: Functions execute inside processes, whether they are defined in a module or not.  Modules are more like namespaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions execute inside processes, whether they are defined in a module or not.

> Dose each module spun up a new process in BEAM ?

Nope.  You can define 50 modules and the functions therein can all execute in a single process.  Modules are more like namespaces.

> When we call a function from another module is there message passing
> been done between two process ?

1. There aren't two processes unless you start two processes.
2. Message passing between processes is done by calling `send/2` or using the operator `!`.  Messages are read inside a process using a `receive clause`.